# Change picture in java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can i change src picture by click the button in JS?

i wrote this function in script

```
function change()
{
var x = document.getElementById("pic");
x.src = "pic.png";
}
```

and i call the function like this

```
<img src="pic.jfif" alt="no pic" width="250px" id="pic">
<button id="btn1" onclick="change();">Change pic</button>
```

**what i miss?**

Comment: You should write a URI/URL as src attribute

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/prop_img_src.asp this has the answer you need. Try to research more!

Comment: document.getElementById('pic').src = 'pic.gif';

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function change() {
            document.getElementById("img").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
        }
    </script>
    <img  id = "img" src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/before_and_after/image-before/Landscape-Color.jpg" alt="">
    <button onclick="change();"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem probably is that you are declaring js function after the button.

Comment: I declaring js function before the button, but Didn't work either

Comment: I glimpse the picture changes and comes back quickly

Comment: well the code I have inside the answer works. As you provided Very little context (that looks fine) I assume issue is somewhere else. You might want to check the console.

Comment: `I glimpse the picture changes and comes back quickly` - Your page may be reloading on button click.